# python code error occur " 'return' outside function"

Tags: python

There is an error that occurs with my python code, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me?? The error that I am getting is

```
"File "tvlattest.py", line 84
 return self._key, self._textin
 SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"
```

Below is my code in python:

```
def newPair(self):
    rand = random.random()
    num_tot = self.num_group1 + self.num_group2
    if num_tot == 0:
        group1 = (rand < 0.5)
    else:
        cutoff = float(self.num_group1) / num_tot
        group1 = (rand < cutoff)

    if group1:
        self._textin = self._textin1

        if AES is not None:
            cipher = AES.new(str(self._key), AES.MODE_ECB)
            self._textin1 = bytearray(cipher.encrypt(str(self._textin1)))
        else:
            self._textin1 = bytearray(16)
            for i in range(0, 16):
                self._textin1[i] = random.randint(0, 255)
            if self.num_group1 > 0:
                self.num_group1 -= 1
    else:
        self._textin = self._interleavedPlaintext
        if self.num_group2 > 0:
            self.num_group2 -= 1

    # Check key works with target
    self.validateKey()

    return self._key, self._textin
```

Comment: The code does not match the error, your *real* indentation or code block must be different (and not indented within a function)

Comment: Your error should be elsewhere (the code you posted seems ok). Check the indent of your return statements at line #84 in file tvlattest.py

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to debug your own code! https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Well, I've tried everything all day and still cannot find the error.Anyway thanks a lot for your help